# How to convert JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>> to DataFrame in Spark Mongo Connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a `JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>>`

```
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext()
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("mongo.input.uri","mongodb://localhost:27017:testDB.testCollection);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>> mongoRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, MongoInputFormat.class, Object.class,
            BSONObject.class).toJavaRDD();
```

How to convert this `mongoRDD` to `DataFrame` so that I can run SQL queries on it?

Comment: did you even get an answer for this? huitseeker's answer is handwavy.

Answer (score 0):

With a SQLcontext imported, you can use [`toDF`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), which requires a list of column names as argument.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get your answer. It would be helpful if you can elaborate a little bit.